# How to extract rentprice from text?

Tags: nlp, text-extraction

For real estate objects I'm trying to extract rent prices from the description text.

E.g.:

`"Für maximalen Komfort sorgt ein Concierge Service, der den Bewohnern im Haus zur Verfügung steht. &lt;br/&gt;Die Wohnung ist seit dem 15.10.2002 zu einer monatlichen Nettokaltmiete in Höhe von 546,25 EUR vermietet. Es bestehen weder Sperrfrist noch Vorkaufsrecht."`

The important part is this here

`Nettokaltmiete in Höhe von 546,25 EUR`

What is a simple way to extract that information?

Caution: There is often other information in EUR - so we can not just search for EUR.

One of my ideas would be:

Split sentences. Check if a sentence includes EUR or €. Check if the sentence also says something about Miete/Jahresmiete and get then the next closest number in €.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way. What are your thoughts on this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dependency parsing.
I wrote this example which should get you started:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
s = "Die Wohnung ist seit dem 15.10.2002 zu einer monatlichen Nettokaltmiete in Höhe von 546,25 EUR vermietet."
doc = nlp(s)

try:
    l = [t for t in doc if 'miete' in t.text.lower() and t.pos_ == "NOUN"]

    if l:
        rent = l[0]
        subtree = [t for t in rent.subtree]
        euro = [t for t in subtree if t.text == "EUR" or t.text == "€"] 
        if euro:
            price = euro[0].nbor(-1)
            if price.like_num == True:
                print(rent, ':', price)
except:
    pass
```

output:

> Nettokaltmiete : 546,25

Comment: Thanks fir this great hint. One quick question to this - how is this compared to NER with key,value? Cause I saw that with "LightTag.io" for example you can do NER and assign to each key a value and train a model.

Comment: If you have lots of labeled data, then training a model can be a good approach, if you don't have lots of labeled data then you have to use hand-crafted rules, such as the one above.

Comment: Ah nice - thanks for this good input! I have quite a lot of data so will rather go for training a model. Your approach helped me a lot for this case though!

Comment: Can you provide a keyword for me? How is this called - having NE that have a key value? I found it once but its hard to search for

Comment: I think what you are talking about is the label of the tagged entity. have a look here: [https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities]